# Export and import database on Git push and pull

Tags: git, mysql, githooks, mysqlimport

I need my database to be in sync across two local computers, without using a server in between. After some research I thought I could use Git hooks to do the task for me.

What I basically want is to run `mysqldump` on `git push` (and add the SQL file to the commit) and `mysqlimport` on `git pull` to and from the remote repository.

I couldn't find any specific hooks for this. I tried the `pre-commit` hook, but this didn't add the SQL file in the current commit. I then tried `prepare-commit`, but without luck.

Has anyone got an answer for this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution by Ben Kulbertis uses the pre-commit and post-merge git hooks to do the job. Works like a charm!

http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a wrapper for your system, maybe "commit.php" or "git-ci.sh" or something. Then you can use bash or perl or python or php or whatever you are comfortable with and run each command one by one, finishing with the commit.

I suggest this after running into similar issues with trying to add to the commit that the pre-commit hook is running. Also, there are no "push" or "pull" hooks on the downstream side (I use a central repository so this might work if you have two machines pushing and pulling with each other as you seem to).

I have a two sided deploy script for one of my web sites where I have a long pre-commit script but on the web server I have a wrapper like this that fetches, then inspects the commit, outputs a report and gives me options about whether to merge and rsync with another server, etc. It replaced a "pull" hook that would probably be a major security hazard.

Hans

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Any idea where I can read more about wrappers?

Comment: I wrote mine in PHP (with calls to exec() and passthru()), since I use PHP the most and it's easy for me. Just use whatever scripting language is easiest for you, maybe python, ruby, bash, perl, whatever. Using the abilities of that language, call the git commands. For instance in php, I would call `exec('/usr/bin/git fetch');` followed on the next line by `exec("/usr/bin/git log --name-only --format=oneline ..origin/master > {$log}");` and then after some checking, `exec("/usr/bin/git merge origin/master");`

Comment: In the end, you can do something like this passthru("/usr/bin/rsync --exclude '/db_backup_svn/*' --exclude '.git' -e ssh -avzp --delete /home/website/ user@192.168.100.2:/home/website/");`

Comment: I do the log command because I dump the changes and display it back as part of an interactive update system, where I can verify that this is the merge they think they are doing, affecting the files they think they are affecting. Just a little eyeball test at the end to make sure things are what they seem.